# How to stack <li> into divs using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat` to iterate over an array to generate `<li>`. But i want to stack every 2 `li` into `div`.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
<ul>
   <div>
       <li>A</li>
       <li>B</li>
   </div>
   <div>
       <li>C</li>
       <li>D</li>
   </div>
</ul>
```

How should i achieve this with ng-repeat?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The only element that may be a child of <ul> is <li>.

Comment: @bhaveshvala What is the relevance between my question and the question to which you have given the reference.

Comment: @Sameer The question is not about what can be the child or not. Its about how to use ng-repeat to achieve this particular requirement.

Comment: @ashfaq.p I would say, that Sameer is trying to help you to see: LI is the only child of UL allowed. You sould check that and adjust your question

Comment: @RadimKöhler i am aware that li is the only child of `ul` but i want to stack li into div so that i can create column of li and display them inline-block.

Comment: @ashfaq.p you can do it with css instead markup

Comment: it seems like [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Grundy Can you help me with how to do it with css. It will be great help.

Comment: can you provide sample how it should look like?

Comment: @ashfaq.p see my answer you can try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is invalid to put div inside ul but to illustrate. i have made a function to split your array into group of 2 element array contained in wrapper array

Or You can also use splice method

**Working Demo 1**

```js
angular.module('testApp',[]).controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items=['1','2','3'];
  
  
  $scope.groupByTwo = function (array)
    {
    var newarray =[];
    index=0;
    for(a=0;a<array.length;a++){
       if(a==0 || a%2==0){
          newarray[index]=[];
          newarray[index].push(array[a]);
      }else{
         newarray[index].push(array[a]);
      }
    if(a!=0)
    index++;
    
    }
  return newarray;
}
  $scope.items=$scope.groupByTwo($scope.items);
});
```

```css
div {
  background:pink; 
  border:1px dotted black;
  margin-top:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  

<ul>
   <div  ng-repeat="item in items">
       <li ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}}</li>
       
   </div>
   
</ul>
```

**Working Demo 2**

You can also use splice method

```js
angular.module('testApp',[]).controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items=['1','2','3'];
  var i,j,temparray=[],chunk = 2;
  for (index=0,i=0,j=$scope.items.length; i<j; i+=chunk,index++) {
    temparray [index]= $scope.items.slice(i,i+chunk);
   }
   $scope.items =temparray;
  
 
});
```

```css
div {
  background:pink; 
  border:1px dotted black;
  margin-top:15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  

<ul>
   <div  ng-repeat="item in items">
       <li ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}}</li>
       
   </div>
   
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply ng-repeat on ul and li will act as a template which will be generated for each item.

Ex :

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items">
        <li>{{item.name}}</li>
     </ul>
```

This will result in

```
<ul>
   <li>name1</li>
   <li>name2</li>
   <li>name2</li>
</ul>
```

If you have a collection consisting of 10 items , you can split them in multiple collections each of size 2 and then apply ng-repeat with each collection on div to get the output you want.